# How can I get more information on Miscellaneous quests in Skryim once they are in my journal?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am accumulating a pile of Miscellaneous quests in my journal, and can't seem to figure out how to refresh my memory on what each one entails.  For example, there is one that is something like "Visit Aventus Aretino", which I recall had something to do with the Dark Brotherhood, but the entry in my journal seems limited to just the words "Visit Aventus Aretino" with no other context.  I am accustomed to just accepting side quests willy nilly and getting to them when I am ready or when opportunity strikes (say I am in the same city where a handful of side quests start).  Now I have at least a dozen of them piled up with very little information available in-game on what they are about.

How can I get more info on these side quests from within the game?  I am having to resort to consulting the internet to refresh my memory on each of these side quests.  In other RPGs the "journal" feature provides much more context, and I am pretty sure Oblivion did as well.

Comment: I'm not sure about your larger question, but I just got that particular quest.  It was a rumor from an innkeep who said that Aventus was a young boy trying to contact the Dark Brotherhood.  No other info was given.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think that there is any additional information in the quest journal about Miscellaneous quests (that is, specifically the quests that get filled under the "Miscellaneous" category in the journal). The one line in the journal is all you get.

(Which, yes, is a surprising choice on Bethesda's part. Most RPGs will give you a paragraph or two about any quest in the journal, but Skyrim seemingly doesn't for Miscellaneous quests.)

However, if you've forgotten the context of the quest (which, as you point out, is very easy to do), you can always turn on quest tracking for that individual quest. Make sure that quest tracking is turned on for the Miscellaneous category as a whole (in the left column), and then turn on quest tracking for the individual quest in the right-hand list. (And maybe turn off quest tracking for other quests.)

Also, don't forget that you can select a Miscellaneous quest and get a map location for that quest.

These will let you at least find the person, place, or thing for that quest, even if you can't recall why or what you need to do with them. In almost all cases, what you need to do becomes clear when you get to the person, place, or thing.

Comment: +1 Getting the map location for the quest is extremely helpful.

Comment: What is "quest tracking" and is it available on consoles?  I am playing on my Xbox.

Comment: I tried this on the Xbox 360, and sure enough I can now find where I can complete these quest. It says in the lower left-hand side of the screen "Pres (A) to toggle active." Once you've activated the main quest, and then the individual quest on the right; just press (X) to see it on the map. You may have to wonder around the map until you find it. Not sure if it will center on the screen when you press X.

I'm completing them with ease now. :)

Answer (score 4):

You have probably activated all of the individual misc quests that you want to do, but you've forgotten one thing.

To be able to view the individual quests, you need to ALSO activate the larger quest (miscellaneous) which is located in the same layer as all the main quests.

Answer (score 0):

If you select misc quests, rather than the individual quests, it should show you all the active ones, so you can do the one you wish or wonder around and do a few, from what i understand you can't do all of them whenever you want, people need to be alvailable, hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Use the spell Clairevoyance to find the objective location. Using this spell will show you the path to the objective.

Comment: That tells you how to get to it.  It doesn't tell you what it was about.